# maximal antichain

Tags: definition, boolean-algebra

I don't understand the definition of Jech (set theory) for "maximal antichain". Let $B$ a boolean algebra and $A$ a subalgebra of $B$. 
$W\subseteq A^+$ is a maximal antichain if $\sum W=1$ and $W$ antichain. As $A^+\subseteq B^+$ and $1\in A^+\cap B^+$, $W$ is also a maximal antichain in $B$ (is there a mistake here ?). But it is saying that $W$ need not be maximal in $B$ .... why ?
Thanks

Comment: Does a maximal antichain $W$ in $A$ satisfy $\sum W=1$ ? If so, the $W$ of Asaf is not maximal in $A$ because $\sum W\neq N$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy to check that $W$ is an antichain in $B$ as well. So we will have to find a way to violate $\sum W = 1$ in $B$. The preservation of finite suprema means we will need to reach for an infinite $W$. An example is below.

---

Consider $B = \mathcal P(\Bbb N)$, and let $A$ be the subalgebra of finite subsets of $\Bbb N$ not containing zero and their complements:

$$A = \{S \subseteq \Bbb N: \text{$S$ finite and $0 \notin S$, or $S$ infinite and $0 \in S$}\}$$

Then the set of singletons of positive integers $W = \{\{n\}: n > 0\}$ is clearly an antichain in $A$, and in $A$, $\sum W = \Bbb N$, while in $B$, $\sum W = \Bbb N_{>0}$.

Comment: I don't see why, in $A$, $\sum W=N$ ... because $N\in W$ ? but, then, why $\sum W$ need to be in $W$ ? because $W$ is complete ? ...

Comment: In a BA, $\sum W$ denotes the supremum of $W$, i.e. the smallest upper bound. It is true that $A$ not necessarily _has_ such a smallest upper bound, but in our case, it has: $\Bbb N$ fulfils the supremum condition, because any set containing all nonzero natural numbers is infinite, hence by construction of $A$ contains $0$ as well; hence contains $\Bbb N$.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot.